# On Visual studio 2013. Win32 app and CLR app

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, clr

actually i'm working on a cpprest application (crossover remote task) on visual studio 2013. It's a win32 consolle application but now i need to parse an XML file. cpprest sdk manages json data but not xml data.
i know visual studio manages xmllite for parsing xml file and i found this tutorial with ax example:
[enter link description here](http://www.functionx.com/vccli/xml/Lesson02.htm)

The problem is that i can't add a CLR app in my win32 solution because /clr option compile is not compatible with others.
I searched on google but i didn't find how to solve it.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Windows comes with an XML library. It is exposed through the [MSXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760399.aspx). Like many system services, this is exposed through a COM interface. You need to be familiar with [COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx).